# Separator for multiple terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to show terms of custom taxonomies. I have that. But, my problem is how to separate when I have multiple terms.
My code:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'member', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <li>
            <h2><?php $terms = get_terms('department');
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo $term->name.' and ';
                }
            ?></h2>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <h5><?php $terms = get_terms('position');
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        echo $term->name.' and ';
                    }
                ?></h5>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">See Full Biography</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

With this I am able to display all terms used (good). But, I need it to say "and" only between terms. Right now, it says "and" after every term, even it's only one term.
I know my problem lies within here:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('department');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name.' and ';
    }
?>
```

How do I only get the "and" to only show between terms and not after every term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just the term names, fetch just the term names: use the `field` parameter for `get_terms()`.

Build a comma separated list with an *and* between the last two items with `wp_sprintf_l()`.

```
// get the term names
$term_names = get_terms( 'department', array ( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
// glue the names with comma and an 'and' between the last two
if ( ! empty ( $term_names ) )
    echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $term_names );
```